# Find All Substrings Interview Query in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

The following is my code for printing all the substrings of an input string. For example, with "abc", it would be "a","ab","abc","b","bc","c". Could someone please review it for efficiency (and possibly suggest alternatives)?

```
void findAllSubstrings(const char *s){
    int x=0;
    while(*(s+x)){
        for(int y=0; y<=x; y++)
            cout<<*(s+y);
        cout<<'\n';
        x++;
    }
    if(*(s+1))
        findAllSubstrings(s+1);
    else
        return;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean buy finding all sub strings? your code seams to print all characters in a string whith "xxx" it seems to print x
xx
xxx
x
xx
x

Comment: That would be all substrings, no? For example, with "abc", it would be "a","ab","abc","b","bc","c".

Comment: How about saying this, findCombinations ?

Comment: one problem with this code is you have the for loop inside a while loop which is O(n^2)

Comment: What about equal substrings in strings like "aaa"? Are you allowed to print "aa" twice?

Comment: @Kinjal Sets have n^2 subsets, so at the base of the problem, n^2 is unavoidable (not to say that this code couldn't be optimized though).

Comment: @Frank No, you can't print any character twice unless it appears twice in succession within the original string, for example, in "aabc".

Comment: @Kinjal I'm not finding combinations either. Finding combinations from "abc" would also involve the string "ac", which is not a substring. It is a different problem.

Comment: @Corbin So how about suggesting some of these optimizations, as this was the original question I posed.

Comment: @JohnRoberts My main suggestion would've been changing from recursive to iterative, though it seems Synxis has already covered that.  From a style point of view, I might be tempted to switch to iterators since you could then generalize the algorithm, but that would probably have worse performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is in O(n²), at least. This seems not to be optimizable. If you want only distinct substrings, then you will have to use a table of already encountered strings, which will make your code slower.

However, you can switch the algorithm from recursive to iterative, which is usually slightly faster. It's a micro-optimization, so do not expect a x2 improvement in speed...

```
void findAllSubstrings2(const char *s)
{
    while(*s)
    {
        int x=0;
        while(*(s + x))
        {
            for(int y = 0; y <= x; y++)
                std::cout << *(s + y);
            std::cout << "\n";
            x++;
        }
        s++;
    }
}
```

I've done a profile test, on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/QcOkVgr6) and [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ug9Nb2) (different versions of same compilers + different machines). The io operations are left for the profile test, because what matters here is the comparison between the 2 functions.

Comment: When an auxiliary stack isn't required and TCO isn't possible, converting recursion to iteration tends to have a very significant performance improvement.  Definitely not a 2x improvement, but I definitely wouldn't consider it a micro optimization.  In the case of a 3 character string, the recursion only goes 3 levels deep.  What if the string were 100 characters?